# counting simple, connected graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I've been thinking about this for a few days, but I haven't found a general solution yet. How many distinct simple, connected, undirected graphs are there of n labelled vertices? For example, there is one for n = 2 and there are four for n = 3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a "simply connected" graph? A tree?

Comment: I count three for $n=3$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I am asking for your definition, not for the number.

Comment: Not necessarily a tree—it can have cycles. That's also why there are four for n=3, rather than just three.

Comment: @Phira: why is my definition relevant? It's the OP we need to hear from.

Comment: @Chris: So does "simply connected" just mean "connected" then?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Sorry.

Comment: Ach, sorry! I meant "simple, connected," not "simply connected," which I don't think is a term in graph theory. That must be the source of confusion.

Comment: Rats.  I thought he was asking about trees.  Funny thing is, I'd been thinking of asking that exact same question.  Depending on the results of this, I still might.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A001187](http://oeis.org/A001187). When looking for this sort of sequence, it's a good idea to first search OEIS, both by text search and by determining the first few terms and searching with them.

Comment: I have written an answer based on the word "labelled", but I am still unsure why the word "distinct" is used in the question.

Comment: See also [this interesting question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68457/number-of-connected-graphs-on-labeled-vertices-counted-according-to-parity).

Comment: @Phira Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm just some kid without much of a mathematics background, so I don't quite get most of your explanation. The first line makes sense, but what was your thought process in introducing G(x) and C(x), and what does the exp function do? Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Do you understand the symbols I have written? As in: Do you know exp and the sigma notation for sums?

Comment: @Phira I'm perfectly comfortable with sigma notation, but not this exp thing.

Comment: @Chris exp is the exponential function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: Oh. Well, now I feel silly. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The number of all labelled simple graphs on $n$ vertices is $g_n=2^{\binom n 2}$ because you can decide for each edge whether to include it.

Now, let $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g_n \dfrac {x^n}{n!}$, let $c_n$ be the number of connected labelled simple graphs on $n$ vertices and let $C(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$

Then, you have the relationship

$$ G(x)=\exp (C(x)) $$

which permits the calculation of the numbers $c_n$, but does not imply a simple formula.

Comment: The function G(x) (above) is undefined for x != 0 as g_n grows faster than n!. To see this, take the log_2 of both 2^(n choose 2) and n! leaving (n choose 2) = n(n-1)/2 and SUM log_2(k) for k from 1 to n. It is also unclear how you get from the definitions of G(x) and C(x) to the relationship G(x) = exp(C(x)) as there is no clear use of simplicity or connectedness shown. Is there a piece missing?

Comment: @Just, it's a formal power series, it doesn't have to converge. A common technique in the use of generating functions.

Comment: When you say permits the calculation, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are given by the [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) $T_n(x,y)$ of the complete graph at the point $(x,y)=(1,2)$.  There are reasonably easy to compute formulae for this polynomial; e.g. [this paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/Pak_Computation_Tutte_polynomial_complete_graphs.pdf) by Igor Pak gives the formula: $$T_{n+1}(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} (x+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{k-1})\ T_k(x,y)\ T_{n-k+1}(x,y).$$

Here's some [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code that implements this:

```
T:=[1];;

ComputeNextCoefficient:=function()
  local n,f,k,q;
  n:=Size(T)+1;
  f:=0;
  for k in [1..n-1] do
    q:=1+Sum([1..k-1],i->2^i);
    if(k=1) then
      f:=f+q*T[n-1];
      continue;
    fi;
    f:=f+Binomial(n-2,k-1)*q*T[k]*T[n-k];;
  od;
  T[n]:=f;;
end;;
```

Then we run it by something like:

```
while(Size(T)<600) do ComputeNextCoefficient(); od;
```

It took 27 seconds to compute the numbers for $1,2,\ldots,600$.

```
gap> T[600];
<integer 123...752 (54096 digits)>
```

Comment: This has been awhile, but can this be used to compute the number of graphs on n vertices with k edges?  I'm a little confused about what the recurrence is compute as the notation seems a little odd to me.  Do the T_n terms represent individual coefficients?